# O que são ^ e $ em uma expressão regular?

Tags: javascript, regex

Em um exercício foi pedido para criar uma regex para validar usuários. Onde seria aceito letras de a-z, _ e -, números de 0-9, mínimo de 3 caracteres e máximo de 16 caracteres.

A resolução do exercício me gerou algumas duvidas sobre o porque está sendo usado o not `^` e também sobre o que seria o símbolo `$`. O professor não explicou na resolução.
segue a expressão:

```
let validarUsuario=/^(?=.{3,16}$)[a-z0-9-_]/
```

Comment: Seja benvindo ao StackOverflow em Português! `^` é marcação de início da string, e `$` é marcação de final. Tem muito material disponível na internet para ler. Para melhorar sua experiência aqui, fazer a pergunta de forma que possa ser respondida, recomendo ler: [Como perguntar](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask),  [Guia de sobrevivência](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/8045/guia-de-sobreviv%c3%aancia-do-stack-overflow-em-portugu%c3%aas) e [Como criar um exemplo Mínimo, Completo e Verificável](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). Obrigado!

Answer (score 4):

Neste caso, `^` não é "not", é um [marcador](https://www.regular-expressions.info/anchors.html) que indica o início da string (embora tenha casos em que funciona como "not", veja mais no final). Já o `$` indica o final da string.

No caso, ele também usou [*lookahead*](https://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) - o trecho entre `(?= )` - que verifica se algo existe à frente. E nesse *lookahead* ele vê se tem de 3 a 16 caracteres, seguido do final da string.

Mas se eu entendi direito, esta regex está errada, veja:

```js
var validarUsuario = /^(?=.{3,16}$)[a-z0-9-_]/;

// deveria ser false, porque tem caracteres que não são letras, números, hífen ou _
console.log(validarUsuario.test('a-&*(&%$#')); // true

// deveria ser false, porque tem espaços
console.log(validarUsuario.test('a   b')); // true
```

Isso porque o *lookahead* verifica se tem de 3 a 16 caracteres até o final da string. Mas o ponto corresponde a qualquer caractere (qualquer um, exceto quebras de linha), o que quer dizer que se a string tiver qualquer coisa, será válida (desde que tenha entre 3 e 16 caracteres). Depois, ela só verifica se tem apenas um caractere que seja letra, número, hífen ou `_` (sim, o trecho `[a-z0-9-_]` corresponde a apenas um caractere, ele não verifica se tem mais).

---

Eu entendi que é para aceitar **apenas** letras de a-z, `_`, `-` e números de 0-9 (ou seja, não pode ter nenhum outro caractere), então deveria ser `/^[-a-z0-9_]{3,16}$/`. Veja a diferença:

```js
var validarUsuario = /^[-a-z0-9_]{3,16}$/;

console.log(validarUsuario.test('a-&*(&%$#')); // false
console.log(validarUsuario.test('a   b')); // false

console.log(validarUsuario.test('abc123-_xyz')); // true
```

Agora o [quantificador](https://www.regular-expressions.info/repeat.html) `{3,16}` é aplicado à [classe de caracteres](https://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html) `[-a-z0-9_]`, ou seja, a string só pode ter de 3 a 16 ocorrências destes - e **somente** destes - caracteres (letras, números, hífen ou `_`).

---

O `^` só significa "not" dentro de uma [classe de caracteres negados](https://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html#negated). Por exemplo, `[^a-z]` é qualquer caractere que não seja uma letra de "a" a "z". Mas quando está fora dos colchetes, ele indica o início da string (ou também o início de linha, caso a regex tenha a [*flag multiline*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/multiline)).

Comment: Nossa!!! muito obrigado pela ajuda. Além de esclarecer as duvidas que eu havia descrevido, você já esclareceu as minhas futuras duvidas rsrsr. Valew mesmo!

Comment: @GabrielPitioti Se a resposta resolveu o seu problema, vc pode aceitá-la, [**veja aqui**](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/1078/112052) como e porque fazê-lo. Não é obrigatório, mas é uma boa prática do site, para indicar a futuros visitantes que aquilo resolveu o problema. Não esqueça que além de aceitar, [**vc também pode votar**](/help/privileges/vote-up), caso tenha achado útil